# Joining two Hex Strings into readable data in Java

Tags: java, string, merge, hex

I need to merge two Hex strings into one.
The first one is composed like this:

```
 while(i=0;i<10;i++){
    int ch = inStream.read();
           String hexch="";
           if (ch >= 0) {
             hexch += Integer.toHexString(ch);  
           }
```

in the stream I reaceave from a serial port the characters ST=0
The second one like this:

```
            String one = ";sp=16;"
            String sqhex="";
            byte[] data = one.getBytes();
                int j;
                for (j=0;j<data.length;j++)
                {
                    sqhex+=Integer.toHexString(data[j]);
                }
```

I need to compose a string with both strings that get me this: "ST=1;sp=16;" in HEX. To do so, I did this:

```
String mensagem =""
mensagem = hexch + sqhex;
```

The thing is that the resulting hex string,

```
53543d31d3b73703d31363b
```

doesn't represent what I need. Instead of "ST=1;sp=16;" I get "ST=1Ó·7Óc"

Is there anyway to merge the hex strings to build what I need?

Thanks

Comment: No clue what you are asking. Try to come up with a **real** [mcve]; but beyond that: please define what you mean by "joining" hex strings. Do you mean "numeric addition"; or just "a" + "b" = "ab" concatenation?! Besides that: please read your input several times before submitting; this stuff is just a **mess**.

Comment: How does concatenating a sequence of hex digits result in `ST=1Ó·7Óc`?  What code are you not showing us?

Comment: @GhostCat I mean doing a concatenation. I can't upload a verifiable example because the whole code has other depencies which I explained above.

Comment: Then you didnt read that [mcve] link. It is not about uploading **all** your code. It is about providing code that shows your problem.

Comment: @VGR the operation results in 53543d31d3b73703d31363b. This, when translated into String results as ST=1Ó·7Óc and not ST=1;sp=16; as I want

Comment: The code doesn't even compile.  For example, you're using a `while` loop as if it's a `for` loop:  `while(i=0;i<10;i++){`    This is not legal Java syntax.

Comment: That “translated into String” is important.  Obviously that is the code that is not providing the result you want, so edit your question and include that code.

Comment: Also, you say that your first input is "ST=1" but your loop is iterating 10 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Integer.toHexString(ch) have a varying length. So the result of your encoding process is not decodable.